# Windows 10 boot is idle for 80 seconds during session init phase

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, wpa

I installed windows 10 enterprise from a DVD. Now the boot takes to long. More specific the "Session Init" phase is idling for about 80 seconds. The ETL file for WPA can be downloaded at 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3f_WdRCKIHWRmxJU0VjQjM1WFE

I would be very thankful for some help with finding the cause for the 80 seconds because I really don't know how to use the analyzer.

Thanks
Heiner

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the services graph, you can see that the LSM ( Local Session Manager) service takes 71s to init:

[image]

This is causing the delay.

[image]

The svchost.exe (720) is waiting for some WorkerThread. Contact the Microsoft Support and send them the ETL. They can analyze this deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. I was able to narrow it down further. It was the ULPS feature of the display driver display driver that caused this. My solution is to disable ULPS as described here: https://community.amd.com/thread/176003

This solution isn't perfect, but it's good enough for me.

As far as I am concerned this is closed.

Bye!

Comment: this is an interesting solution. I never heard about ULPS and can't see any AMD related calls.