# PC all of a sudden takes <85 seconds to boot, why? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, boot

So I recently completed a fresh install of Windows 10 (UEFI) and my boot times were sub 15 seconds, from power on to login. A few days ago my PC started to boot up incredibly slowly with times of up to 85 seconds and more! People online have told me this isn't considered very "slow" but when you're used to times like 15 seconds I've started to become impatient whilst waiting for my PC to boot.

I've tried various things, including:

- Enabling Fast Boot
- Updating drivers
- Disabling start-up programs that aren't required to run on startup
- Made sure the boot order in BIOS is set to my boot drive first
- Unplugging all USB devices before boot
- Disabling Intel Management Engine Interface (I seen this could be a problem)

I have ran a test using Windows Performance Recorder and tried analysing the results myself but can't seem to make any sense of the data. Is someone able to take a look for me and potentially find what could be making my PC hang for so long after the Windows logo appears?

You can find my .etl file here: [Boot .ETL File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16hpEVa9rN7A3hj4r0UoxT0wucOyQKF82/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check that your CPU isn't over temperature and throttling thermally....

Comment: @Mokubai I checked temps also, CPU is max 29°C :/

Comment: https://imgur.com/V5GzbRv Maybe Google LSM slow boot. One example - https://superuser.com/questions/1168423/windows-10-boot-is-idle-for-80-seconds-during-session-init-phase

Comment: Maybe to do with: nvlddmkm.sys?

Comment: @HelpingHand I took a look at the nvlddmkm.sys issue online but could only find things related to BSOD and error messages saying the Nvidia driver has crashed, I however aren't getting any of these issues but I shall try some fixes related to these issues after work and see if they help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried some more steps and diagnosed the problem. Turns out the graphics driver was causing the slow boot. After reinstalling the driver I'm back down to 21 seconds for a full boot which I'm happy with.

Steps taken to diagnose the problem:

- Unplug graphics card and reboot - 13 seconds for a full boot
- Plugged graphics card back in and reboot - 80 seconds
- Un-installed graphics driver and reboot - 18 seconds
- Re-installed graphics driver with a custom install and checked the "fresh install" option - 21 seconds

Hopefully this helps someone else with similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to show your work and results, so that someone in the future can see the potential fix.